# How do you call a method with multiple arrays as input?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, call

What I'm trying to do is call a method that takes two arrays as an input. It would look something like this.

```
pairs({2,3,4}, {1,0,2});
```

The problem I end up having is that it's an illegal start of an expression. I've tried using braces instead and have come up with the same problem.

```
pairs([2,3,4], [1,0,2]);
```

Is there a way to call a method using arrays like this or do I have to declare an array?

Comment: Try using this: `pairs(new int[] {2,3,4}, new int[] {1,0,2});`

Comment: You can only get away without the `new int[]` bit when you are declaring and assigning in the same line. `int[] array = {1, 2, 3};` is ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are pretty close: all you need to do is to add `new` operator, and provide the array type, like this:

```
pairs(new int[] {2,3,4}, new int[] {1,0,2});
```

Comment: Thanks! I completely forgot about adding the operator and type.